# setting encoding for CSV file generated by exportButton in Oracle Application Framework

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, character-encoding, jdeveloper, oracle-apps

Is it possible to set encoding for exported data from OAF page? 
I have some polish letters like 'ś' or 'ć' and OAF page shows it correctly but in exported CSV file these letters are shown as '?'

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread for you which might be relevant:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3151892

Comment: zeoneozero - thanks for your reply. Unfortunately problem is not with encoding on a page, but in exported file. Does anybody know where from does OAF take encoding configuration to export data with exportButton?